# I have 5 statutes and i need to be sure that 3 statutes are occupied by 3 different person

Tags: c#, linq

this is my first post so i apologize if i fail in some questions but i will try to be clear so you can follow me.

I am creating a program that checks if a partner (from the company i work) has a valid statute (Premium Partner, Certified Partner and Solutions Partner). To confirm that, i check if their Technicians have valid certifications and everything is running ok for Certified Partner and Solutions Partner.

So for Premium partners i have to check if they have the 5 statutes needed BUT 3 person have to take 3 distinct statutes.

So every partner statute has a rule that i created and it works fine because it only checks for those 5 statutes. So for Premiun partner i need to do some work after the rule validation.

```
public async Task<bool> ValidateThirdPartyTypeRuleAsync(Partner partner, SpecializationExecutionThirdPartyType thirdPartyType)
{

    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thirdPartyType.CRPValidationRule))
        {
            //Check if rule is valid
            using (var rule = new Evaluate(typeof(Partner), thirdPartyType.CRPValidationRule))
            {
                if (partner == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Partner", "Partner cannot be null for ValidateThirdTypeRule execution");
                }

                //Run rule with partner
                var result = await rule.RunAsync(partner);

                if ((bool)result == true && partner.ThirdPartyType == "PPP")
                {
                    //Gets a list of technicians with valid satatutes for "PPP"
                    List<Technician> ValidTechnicianList = partner.Technicians.FindAll(s => 
                    s.StatutesHistory.Exists(a => (new int[] { 6, 11, 12, 8, 9 }).Contains(a.StatuteID) && a.Active)).ToList();

                    //Returns if partner is valid for the statute
                    if (ValidTechnicianList.Count() >= 3)
                    {
                            return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                //Returns if partner is valid for his statute
                return (bool)result;
            }
      }
  }
```

So as you can imagine, this "Count>=3" doesn't do the job because if 1 technician as the 5 needed certifications and the other 2 technicians have only one and the same it will return "True".

This is the RULE for Premiun Partners:

```
Technicians.Where(a => a.StatutesHistory.Exists(b => new int[] {6, 11}.Contains(b.StatuteID) && b.Active == true)).Count() >= 1 && 
Technicians.Where(a => a.StatutesHistory.Exists(b => new int[] {12}.Contains(b.StatuteID) && b.Active == true)).Count() >= 1 &&  
Technicians.Where(a => a.StatutesHistory.Exists(b => new int[] {8}.Contains(b.StatuteID) && b.Active == true)).Count() >= 1 &&  
Technicians.Where(a => a.StatutesHistory.Exists(b => new int[] {9, 25}.Contains(b.StatuteID) && b.Active == true)).Count() >= 1 &&  
Technicians.Where(a => a.StatutesHistory.Exists(b => new int[] {5, 26}.Contains(b.StatuteID) && b.Active == true)).Count() >= 1
```

Thanks in advance
and keep up the good work

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: sorry don't know why it appeared

Comment: If you want to get 3 persons who have distinct 3 values, why don't you use `Distinct()` method? Can you share sample data you have to filter? Seems you have to return valid technicians list with their statuses.

Comment: Because in this ValidTechnicianList i already have distinct Technicians. They don´t repeat. i Have to make sure that the Project Manager, Area Consultant and Senior consultant are 3 distinct technicians. The Id numbers are inside that array (PM = 6, AC = 11, SC = 12 )

Comment: @MaciejLos as far as I understand, it would be ok to have three technicans that all have all 5 certifications, since 3 distinct statutes could be assigned to them in any combination. The only problem is the case of one technican having (nearly) all certifications and all other technicans having only the same single certification.

Comment: @grek40 really understood the problem!

Comment: Please remove `entity-framework` tag as well. Even LINQ is not quite precise because you seem to be using `List<T>` specific methods, but anyway, it can stay.

Comment: @IvanStoev done, but your comment didnt help at all :\

Comment: I used List<T> just to try to show you guys what i tried and failed

Comment: Why did the awnser disapeared? did someone deleted it?

Comment: Yes, it was deleted (probably by the author, because he understood your problem and his solution was wrong)

Comment: hhmmm probably, i think i still can have a "false" True by using his solution. Because when i look manually to the data im using i can see that technicias have a lot of repeated certifications so using Count wont be the solution.

Comment: Maybe a little to heavy for your problem, but you should have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of all, apologies, my previous answer was plainly wrong. What you need here is a way to generate cartesian products from a varying number of collections.

[Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert?tab=answers) has a wonderful article on this subject and an extremely elegant solution you can find in the following article: [Computing a Cartesian Product with LINQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/).

```
//Eric Lippert's implementation
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this 
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    var emptyProduct =
        new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };

    return sequences.Aggregate(
      emptyProduct,
      (accumulator, sequence) =>
        from accseq in accumulator
        from item in sequence
        select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
}
```

And now, your problem is easily solved:

```
 var requiredDistinct = new[] { 6, 11, 12 };
 var distinctStatutes = 
    technicians.Select(t => t.StatuteIds)
               .CartesianProduct()
               .Select(p => p.Distinct())
               .Where(p => requiredDistinct.All(
                  requiredId => p.Contains(requiredId)));
```

1. We compute the cartesian products of all statute ids.
2. We filter out duplicate ids calling `Distinct` on each product.
3. We then filter out all those products where not all the required statutes are present.

And now our condition is met only and only if:

```
if (distincStatues.Count() >= requiredDistinct.Length)
{ 
    //condition met
}
```

Comment: So i am trying this solution and i get an error from your linq expression because it cannot convert drom IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<T>[] can i cast it somewhere?

Comment: @MiguelVale I don't know the exact structure of your types so you'll have to adapt it slighlty to your needs. The error you are getting can't be fixed with a cast, your pasing in an array of `IEnumerable<T>`s wher an `IEnumerable<T>` is expected. Understand the code in the answer and use it in your specific scenario.

Comment: i didn't really understand your solution at start, but i read the article you sent and i use it in my specific scenario and it is working. I really want to thank you for this, finally i can finish my project!!! Keep up the good work in the amazing comunity!

Comment: @MiguelVale glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

A general solution (working with any number of constraints) would be to create an actual result with backtracking or a different technique.

Assign a technician for each required statute/certificate, check the constraints as rules.

```
/// <summary>
/// recursive solution (backtracking)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Technicians">All technicians (possibly pre-filtered so they have at least one relevant certificate)</param>
/// <param name="DistinctSlots">The resulting statute assignment. The input needs to satisfy correctnessRule(DistinctSlots)</param>
/// <param name="ProcessingSet">The statute IDs to be assigned according to the rules</param>
/// <param name="completenessRule">A predicate that checks the completeness of a result. It will be applied when a possible solution is fully assigned</param>
/// <param name="correctnessRule">A predicate that checks the correctness of an assignment. It needs to be true even for valid sub-results where some statutes are not assigned</param>
/// <returns>True if DistinctSlots contains a solution</returns>
private static bool FillSlots(List<Technician> Technicians, Dictionary<int, Technician> DistinctSlots, IEnumerable<int> ProcessingSet, Predicate<Dictionary<int, Technician>> completenessRule, Predicate<Dictionary<int, Technician>> correctnessRule)
{
    if (!ProcessingSet.Any())
    {
        return completenessRule(DistinctSlots);
    }
    var key = ProcessingSet.First();
    var nextSet = ProcessingSet.Skip(1);
    foreach (var tech in Technicians.Where(x => x.StatutesHistory.Any(y => y.StatuteID == key)))
    {
        DistinctSlots[key] = tech;
        if (correctnessRule(DistinctSlots) &&
            FillSlots(Technicians, DistinctSlots, nextSet, completenessRule, correctnessRule))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    DistinctSlots.Remove(key);
    return false;
}
```

A complete result must satisfy the completenessRule, which could be implemented as

```
private static int[] StatuteIDs = new int[] { 6, 11, 12, 8, 9 };
private static bool CompletenessRule(Dictionary<int, Technician> assignment)
{
    // ensure all statuteIDs are available as keys in the dictionary and all values are not-null
    return !StatuteIDs.Except(assignment.Keys).Any() &&
        assignment.Values.All(x => x != null);
}
```

A correct result must satisfy the correctnessRule. This example rule would allow a technician to have multiple statutes (9, 12, ...) but it would require distinct technicians for the statutes 6, 8 and 11:

```
private static bool CorrectnessRule(Dictionary<int, Technician> assignment)
{
    return
        CompareNullOrDifferent(assignment, 6, 8) &&
        CompareNullOrDifferent(assignment, 6, 11) &&
        CompareNullOrDifferent(assignment, 8, 11);
}
private static bool CompareNullOrDifferent(Dictionary<int, Technician> assignment, int key1, int key2)
{
    Technician t1, t2;
    return
        !assignment.TryGetValue(key1, out t1) ||
        !assignment.TryGetValue(key2, out t2) ||
        t1 != t2;
}
```

Execute the solver as follows:

```
Dictionary<int, Technician> DistinctSlots = new Dictionary<int, Technician>();

bool foundResult = false;
foundResult = FillSlots(Technicians, DistinctSlots, StatuteIDs, CompletenessRule, CorrectnessRule);

if (!foundResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not enough different technicians");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enough different technicians");
}
```

With some `List<Technician> Technicians` input.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the first check (all 5 statuses present) by this query:

```
var hasAllRequired = !(new int[] { 6, 11, 12, 8, 9 }
    .Except(partner.Technicians
        .SelectMany(t => StatutesHistory.Select(h => h.StatuteID))).Any());
```

And the second check by this query:

```
var pass3Check = partner.Technicians
    .Select(t => t.StatutesHistory.Select(h => h.StatuteID).Distinct().Count())
    .Count(statusCount => statusCount >= 3) >= 3;
```

The last query first creates a list of counts of distinct statuses per technician (the part until `Count())`) and then checks if at least 3 of these have a count of 3 or more.

By the way, you could make your life a lot easier by introducing an `enum` for your status values.

Comment: i am sorry because i am not an expert but this is givving me an error "SelectMany(t = StatutesHistory))" is it well written?

Comment: List<StatuteHistory> Technicians.StatutesHistory

Comment: OK, I think this is what you need.

Comment: yes no more error, now i will test it. you still missed (t => tttttt.Statutes...) only 1 "t" ofc, just to get it better

Comment: Sorry friend but this doesn't work because it checks if a technician has 3 or more statutesID, but it is possible that a technician as 3 and the other two techs have only 1, and your code returns false :\

Comment: Your requirement is "3 person have to take 3 distinct statutes". My code counts the number of technicians having at least three different statuses, doesn't it?